# SAS Proc Print - No Output

Tags: sas, proc

I am so frustrated. I can't even get a proc print to work. I've tried so many things. I don't see the table in results viewer. My log says the file has been read and that I should see results. I've tried turning ods off and on and saving to work folder or saving to my own folder. I've tried switching to a list output. Right now, I just want this code to run which I got from: https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/270-2011.pdf .

```
data energy;
length state $2;
input region division state $ type expenditures @@;
datalines;
1 1 ME 1 708 1 1 ME 2 379 1 1 NH 1 597 1 1 NH 2 301
1 1 VT 1 353 1 1 VT 2 188 1 1 MA 1 3264 1 1 MA 2 2498
1 1 RI 1 531 1 1 RI 2 358 1 1 CT 1 2024 1 1 CT 2 1405
1 2 NY 1 8786 1 2 NY 2 7825 1 2 NJ 1 4115 1 2 NJ 2 3558
1 2 PA 1 6478 1 2 PA 2 3695 4 3 MT 1 322 4 3 MT 2 232
4 3 ID 1 392 4 3 ID 2 298 4 3 WY 1 194 4 3 WY 2 184
4 3 CO 1 1215 4 3 CO 2 1173 4 3 NM 1 545 4 3 NM 2 578
4 3 AZ 1 1694 4 3 AZ 2 1448 4 3 UT 1 621 4 3 UT 2 438
4 3 NV 1 493 4 3 NV 2 378 4 4 WA 1 1680 4 4 WA 2 1122
4 4 OR 1 1014 4 4 OR 2 756 4 4 CA 1 10643 4 4 CA 2 10114
4 4 AK 1 349 4 4 AK 2 329 4 4 HI 1 273 4 4 HI 2 298
;

proc sort data=energy out=energy_report;
by region division type;
run;

proc format;
value regfmt 1='Northeast'
2='South'
3='Midwest'
4='West';
value divfmt 1='New England'
2='Middle Atlantic'
3='Mountain'
4='Pacific';
value usetype 1='Residential Customers'
2='Business Customers';
run;


ods html file='my_report.html';
proc print data=energy_report;
run;
ods html close;
```

My log shows no errors:

```
NOTE: Writing HTML Body file: my_report.html
1582 proc print data=energy_report;
1583 run;

NOTE: There were 44 observations read from the data set WORK.ENERGY_REPORT.
NOTE: PROCEDURE PRINT used (Total process time):
real time 0.04 seconds
cpu time 0.00 seconds
```

When I go into my temporary files, I can open the "energy" and "energy_report" data set and I can view all the data. Why can't I see a print output? I'm not sure what I'm missing. I checked the output window, the results viewer window, and all the generated html files. They're all blank.

Thank you

Comment: Did you find the file `my_report.html`? What version of SAS are you using and what type (EG, Studio, PC). I would check the my_report.html but there are easier ways so you're doing something weird or it's set up weird.

Comment: A quick fix, change the path of the file to a location you know the full file path, check the file for the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a lot on your set up, but I would enable HTML & Listing output and then check the output.

```
ods listing;
ods html;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
```

If you're using EG the results should be in the process flow. If Studio, in the Results tab, if SAS Base, click on Results and open if necessary. 
There is an option called 'Show Results as Generated' and it's possible it's been set to off in your installation for some reason. I often set mine up this way because I often generate a lot of files at once (HTML/XLSX) and don't want them to open up automatically.

Comment: Is it not "ods close listing"?

Comment: Thank you Reeza. I played around with all those settings. I turned ods listing on and off (both inline and using the settings). I had already played around with generating results automatically, saving the html files to work folder vs my own local folder, but results viewer won't even open up and the options window shows nothing. I eventually gave up this morning after realizing I have access to SAS Studio too. Everything runs fine in SAS studio, so I have really no clue what I'm doing wrong with EG. I'm sure this error is on my end lol.

Comment: SAS Base not EG***

Comment: Wow I just re-opened SAS Base and just ran the file and everything worked fine. Guess I'll never know why. I spent hours playing with the settings yesterday. Thank you, all.

Comment: You probably accidentally turned on noresults or all the destinations. Glad its working now though.

Answer (score 0):

Where you print to `my_report.html`, the file will probably be trying to go to C:\my_report.html - put in a full file path instead, and check that when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
ods html file='my_report.html';
proc print data=energy_report;
run;
ods html close;
```

to

```
ods html file="&path./my_report4.html";
proc print data=energy_report;
run;
ods html close;
```

where `&path` contains the path where the file will be created.

**And important : Use " instead of '.** Double quote in the place of a quote.